# FCKEditor doesn't work in IE10

Tags: fckeditor, internet-explorer-10

FCKEditor doesn't appear in IE10. When I go to IE development tools and switch browser mode to IE9, FCKEditor works all right. But when I put meta tag for emulate IE9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

into header of my web-page, it doesn't help me. How to make FCKEditor work? Or are there another ways for emulating IE9 within IE10?

Comment: Any chance that you can upgrade to CKEditor? I don't think FCKEditor is maintained anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

**Mozilla 17**

in fckeditorcode_gecko.js

**find this>>**

```
if (A.IsGecko){var B=s.match(/gecko\/(\d+)/)[1];A.IsGecko10=((B<20051111)||(/rv:1\.7/.test(s)));A.IsGecko19=/rv:1\.9/.test(s);}else A.IsGecko10=false;}
```

**and replace with>>**

```
if (A.IsGecko){var B=s.match(/gecko\/([0-9.]+)/)[1];if(B != "17.0"){A.IsGecko10=((B<20051111)||(/rv:1\.7/.test(s)));}A.IsGecko19=/rv:1\.9/.test(s);}else A.IsGecko19=true;}
```

in fckeditor.php

**find this>>**

```
return ($iVersion >= 20030210);
```

**and replace with>>**

```
//return ($iVersion >= 20030210);

return true;
```

Answer (score 13):

**//IE10**

in **fckeditor.js** > method : FCKeditor_IsCompatibleBrowser

**find this:**

```
var sBrowserVersion = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE (.\..)/)[1] ;
```

and **replace with:**

```
var sBrowserVersion = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1] ;
```

in **fckeditorcode_ie.js**

**find**

```
e.scopeName!='HTML'
```

and **change if condition to:**

```
if(FCKBrowserInfo.IsIE&& e.scopeName && e.scopeName!='HTML')
```

**find**

```
D.parentElement().document!=B
```

and **change if to:**

```
if(D.parentElement().document && D.parentElement().document!=B)
```

**find**

```
B.open("GET",A,false);
```

and **add this:**

```
B.open("GET",A,false);
try {
    B.responseType = "msxml-document";
} catch(e) {};
B.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

IE10 is not working well with it's new quirks mode.

You can switch to the older, basic quirks mode they develop and your problem will be solved.
Add the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

Also make sure you detect the browser and and it's version as IE10 and then apply this meta tag.

Comment: also make sure you detect the browser and and it's version as IE10 and then apply this meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />`

.

and find & replace the regex in ckeditor JS codes:

replace `/MSIE (\d+)/` with `/MSIE ([\d.]+)/`

---

Most importantly, dont forget to **Close the browser/tab** and open the site again. Otherwise this meta tag wont work  !

Answer (score 0):

My solution after hours of debugging was pretty simple.

I make the fckeditor.js include the last javascript include.  If it was buried in between a bunch of other js includes it would fail in IE 10.  When I dropped it down to the last javascript file to include it worked.