# FCKeditor version 2.6.4 ASP classic not show tool bar on IE11 Win8.1

Tags: asp-classic, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11, fckeditor

FCKEditor tool bar doesn't appear in IE11. When I go to IE development tools(F12) and switch browser profile to Enterprise, FCKEditor works all right. But I don't want to all my users need change browser setting to use FCKEditor.

I tried [FCKEditor doesn't work in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639541/fckeditor-doesnt-work-in-ie10), but doesn't help in IE11. I don't think change browser setting is a good option. Could anyone have any suggestion to fix this issue on FCKeditor code itself?

Comment: Note that recent versions of IE revert to "Compatibility Mode" for Intranet sites, including localhost. Make sure this is not happening to you. See this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8) for what to do if you are working on an intranet site or disable the setting in IE on your dev machine.

Comment: It's a known bug, which has been resolved in the latest version of CKEditor (as it has been renamed)  Unfortunately the dedicated support for Classic ASP has been dropped - as I'm sure you know.  As you have discovered, the toolbar appears in compatibility mode, you could try using a meta tag to force IE to emulate an earlier version - eg `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` but it's hardly an ideal solution

Comment: Thanks, @John. In this case, we cannot update to CKEditor, is any way could control IE11 Browser Profile to default Enterprise mode Programmatically using meta tag?

Comment: It looks as if with IE11 it is no longer possible to use a meta tag to force the browser into compatibility mode.  The user has to turn it on via the toolbar.  Using tools which are no longer supported will often throw up problems like this I'm afraid

Comment: FCKeditor is totally outdated, you should upgrade to CKEditor right now because sooner or later you'll have to do, so better do it now and don't waste the time trying to workaround problems that have a clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not a solution but what I've done.

I only use the text editor for admin logins and never public side - it's too open to abuse. I used to ise FCK editor but found a security issue allowing annoymous uploads.

There is a similar issue with IE with CuteSoft's version. So maybe it's javascript and IE? I haven't the time to explore it so I've tried a halfway house which is to detect the browser and then prompt the user with what to do to change settings.

Most client's are happy with this or just seem to take the practical solution of simply switching to Chrome for admin tasks!